# Initialization of variable

Tags: java

```
int seqno = 0; 
seqno++;

String seq = String.valueOf(seqno);
Firebase postRef = rootRef.child("employee");
Map<String, String> post1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

post1.put("Seqno", seq);
```

i want to store the seq number in firebase, each time when I try to add seq number to firebase it has to increament and add. eg: 1,2,3..

My problem is because of initializing seqno to 0 , every time it gets initialized and add as 1,1,1...

[Firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya0UG.png)

i have to retrieve only the path field from sub-trees. how can I do that?

can anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: More context is likely needed to be able to answer this. If you want a static counter you can declare a static field in your class and increment that instead.

Comment: Define `seqno` as global/instance variable, instead of local. Or pull last added seq number from firebase and assign it to `seqno` instead of just `int seqno = 0;`

Comment: When is 'every time'? Who is calling this code? When? How often?

Comment: does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/28915706/4290096

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the code that adds the SeqNo to firebase inside a function...and call it...
Keep the initialization statement outside...
something like..

```
private static int seqno = 0; 


public void AddSquence(int seqno)
{
String seq = String.valueOf(seqno);
Firebase postRef = rootRef.child("employee");
Map<String, String> post1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
post1.put("Seqno", seq);

    if(seqno > max)
      {
       System.exit(0);
      }
   else
    {
    AddSquence(seqno+1);
    }

    }
```

Comment: what Value i have to pass while calling the function ?? AddSequence(value)

Comment: call it with the sqn no. = 1..and make the function recursive...so that function keeps calling itself until seqno > yourDesiredNumber

Answer (score 0):

You can always make "seqno" as a class member: field of the class like this:

```
public class MyClass{
  private int seqno;
  ....
}
```

Comment: That's not 'global', it is a class member.